# jquery each with json object

Tags: jquery, html, each

i have this json response:

```
[{
    "i": 39,
    "id": "15399"
},
{
    "i": 38,
    "id": "15386"
},
{
    "i": 37,
    "id": "15329"
}]
```

now i need to put these elements in a html list. how can i use $.each to do that?

(something like:

```
39: 15399
38: 15386
```

etc...)

(btw. i have no access to the file that generates the json code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just iterate over your array, for example:

```
var list = $("#myList");
$.each(data, function(i, obj) {
  $("<li />", { text: obj.i + ": " + obj.id }).appendTo(list);
});
```

In a [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) callback, you get the index and the object as parameters, in this case you just want to use the `i` and `id` properties off that.  The alternative is just a ordinary `for` loop, like this:

```
var list = $("#myList");
for(var i=0, l=data.length; i<l; i++) {
  var obj = data[i];
  $("<li />", { text: obj.i + ": " + obj.id }).appendTo(list);
});
```

Comment: i have the json response in a variable called result, that means i should replace 'data' with 'result'?

Comment: @user495208 - yup that's it :)

Comment: you need to parse the json with var responseObj = $.parseJSON(responseObj) first then iterate over the object

Comment: @Hersheezy - jQuery does this already if the response is JSON, assuming you either specify json, use `$.getJSON()`, or the headers are set correctly...I'd hope one of those is true :)

Comment: @craver: correct. you only need to parse it if you use $.get() or $.post() without specifying. I usually use $.getJSON() or $.postJSON()

Comment: @Hersheezy - There a `$.postJSON()` added I'm not aware of? :)

Comment: can you tell me whats wrong with: 

<pre><code>for (var i=0, l=result.length; i<l; i++) { var a = result[i]; $({ text: a.id }).appendTo.('#listResponses'); }</code></pre> 

because nothing happens...

Comment: @user495208 - you have a lot of extra syntax in there, e.g. the `.` before `('#listResponses')`...you should be seeing some JavaScript errors.  I can't tell completely though, you need to wrap your comment code in backticks.

Comment: @user495208 - I don't see the `<li>` in your code...wrap your comment code in backticks (shift + ~ key) on each side for me to see it :)  I it is there, I think you're missing the comma, it should be:  `$("<li />", { text: a.i + ": " + a.id }).appendTo('#listResponses');`

Answer (score 0):

No need, it is just a javascript array - you can just use a for loop...

```
for(var idx=0;idx<JSONResponse.length;idx++){
    var elem=JSONResponse[idx];
    $('ul#somewhere').append('<li>'+elem.i+': '+elem.id+'</li>');
}
```

Comment: You should not use a `for...in` loop to *iterate* over an array, it's for *enumerating* an object.